# LXD Bridge Prevents Network Access

Tags: network-bridge, lxd, subnet

**Explanation before the question**

I am trying to configure LXD on a raspberry pi using Ubuntu Core 20.04. It's local IP is initialized as `192.168.2.64`. Before I run `lxd init` it was connecting to network without problem. Towards the configuration process, I created a network bridge with address 192.168.2.33/27, which should allow the range `192.168.2.33-62` to containers. However, after saving the configuration file the Pi is disappeared from the local network. When I plug in the HDMI cable, it says it is accessible over `192.168.2.64` and shows a link to the Ubuntu account page. I cannot access it via network, nor by plugging directly a keyboard (a Ubuntu Core thing I guess?).

**Now the questions**

Is there something wrong with my subnet for the network bridge, or did I messed up something else in the process? How could I connect and reconfigure the device, or alter the files in the micro SD card that the OS is installed? I don't want to delete the contents of the disk if possible.

I am far less familiar with networking than an average bear, so any explanation or additional support is also appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like when you where using the out of the box lxdbr0 it all worked correctly but when you created your own bridge it stopped working.    That is typically because its not configured for NAT.  

Can you supply more details on your bridge configuration and how thats integrated into your LXD containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, don't know why but I though I must give different IP addresses for bridge and the host device. I was giving ethernet eth0 interface and the lxdbr0 different IPs at the same time. It is restored when I removed entries for eth0, and let bridge configure the device IP as well. I misunderstood how bridges work apparently.